# React conditional statement within a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying reviews from the Google Maps API. Within my map function I only want to display reviews that are higher than a `1` rating. How can I update my map function to only display reviews where `review.rating > 1`?

```
{this.state.reviews && this.state.reviews.map((review, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="review">
        <p>{review.text}</p>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: instead of just immediately returning the JSX you could change it to a regular arrow function and run a check like `if(review.rating ==1) return null;` and then just wrap the rest of the JSX in a return statement as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just filter them before map:

```
{this.state.reviews
    .filter((review) => review.rating > 1) // get only reviews with rating > 1
    .map((review, index) => (
       <div key={index} className="review">
          <p>{review.text}</p>
       </div>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If, for some reason you don't want to call the `.filter` method on the array, you could do something like this. Basically you are calling a ternary operator in your return. Let me know if you need any more explanation.

```js
{this.state.reviews && this.state.reviews.map((review, index) => (
  review.index > 1
   ? (<div key={index} className="review">
        <p>{review.text}</p>
    </div>)
   : null
))}
```